# How to detect that the current element is the last element when iterating using Symbol.iterable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iterator

Looping on an array by calling iterable explicitly, sample code below:

```
let sampleArr = [4, 3, 56, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9];
let sampleArrIter = sampleArr[Symbol.iterator]();

while (true) {
    let iterBody = sampleArrIter.next();
    if (iterBody.done) {
        //loop ends 
        break;
    } else {
        //loop continues - current element - iterBody.value
    }
}
```

I want to be able to detect that the current element is the last element in the array so that I can perform an action specifically after loop ends. When using a for loop I do this by comparing the array length and the current index.   How can I do that using Symbol.iterator?

Comment: why not move the after looping part behind the loop?

Comment: I need the last element also to work with

Comment: why not do the last thing in `if (iterBodu.done) { doLastThing(); break } else { doNormalThing(); }`? Here is great article https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-es6-iterators-in-javascript-with-examples-189d052c3d8e

Comment: because when iterBody.done is true, iterBody.value == undefined

Comment: I know I could put the last element value in a variable to check on when iterBody.done, but I am looking for a place where the value is already kept, instead of the variable declared by me

Comment: At present I guess I could work with just sampleArr[sampleArr.length - 1], and get the last element

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, may be it will help you

```
  let sampleArr = [4, 3, 56, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9];
  let sampleArrIter = sampleArr[Symbol.iterator]();
  let lastIterator = sampleArrIter.next();
  let val = lastIterator.value;

  while (!lastIterator.done) {
     val = lastIterator.value;
     lastIterator = sampleArrIter.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```js
let sampleArr = [4, 3, 56, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9];
let sampleArrIter = sampleArr[Symbol.iterator]();
let lastElValue, lastElIndex = -1;

while (true) {
    let iterBody = sampleArrIter.next();
    if (iterBody.done) {
        // do something with last element
      console.log(`${lastElValue} : ${lastElIndex}`)
        break;
    } else {
      lastElValue = iterBody.value
      lastElIndex++
        //loop continues - current element - iterBody.value
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure this works, I want to make sure that when using Symbol iterators the array index is not available anywhere else (like in some property or prototype) and we need to get the index values by giving our own variable declarations. Also, that when {done: true}, the last value is not available anywhere else in the iterator. So that I dont need to declare our own variables to hold the last value